# How to set the result count of a select statement in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to set the result count of my query in SQL Server 2008. Something like Oracle's rownum.

Is that even possible in SQL Server?

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that you only want, for example, the first 10 rows when there may be dozens or hundreds? If that is what you are seeking, you use **`TOP`**.

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Customers
```

You just have to be careful of the sort order, if you care about it. Just like in Oracle.

And you might want only `DISTINCT` records.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the rows numbered you can use something like

```
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY modelid) AS rownum FROM models
```

which will number the result set sequentially.

If you want to use it to limit your result set, you should in TSQL instead use a [TOP](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) expression.

Answer (score 0):

Others have pointed out the Top function but you can also [`set ROWCOUNT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx) This will stop the command once that number of rows are affected. Really handy to break up large deletes for example.

As the notes point out, this is deprecated and the TOP syntax will be needed in the future.